# Wrong way of storing date in mongo prevent deleting

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I can't properly delete elements from the array in MongoDB, because it's storing dates in the wrong way.

I adding the date as an array of: `'2021-04-24T00:00'` - `YYY-MM-DDT00:00` format.
Mongo shows it as `'2021-04-24T22:00'` - it adds `22:00`

I can't delete it via:
`updateOne({ _id: car_id }, { "$pullAll": { "reserved": days } });`
Mongo also shows date before! So in case when it should store array with days from `2021-03-02 to 2021-03-10` it stores dates `2021-03-01 to 2021-03-09`. And then deleting doesn't work!
How to fix it? I read all of the threads at stack but nothing works for me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This might be  a timezone issue, MongoDB stores date types in UTC.

Answer (score 1):

I changed field in Schema from `Date` to `String` now it works, but I know that I shouldn't have done it.

Comment: You should do the other way around, i.e. convert the `String` to `Date` values. Function [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) is your friend.